# Dynamic programming: find the subset with product of all members is equals to given number

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I will find an algorithm for this problem.

> Input: array of n integers and number k
>
> We must find a set of numbers from array, that product of all this numbers in set equals to k is

I think, I must use dynamic programming for this task. But I have no idea, how to use it.

Comment: Looks like [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), just with different operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is similar to the subset sum problem, where you are required to find a subset whom sum is a value `k`.

Since there is a solution to your problem (you have a subset `S` whom multiplication is `k`) if and only if you have a subset of log(x) for each x in the set, whom sum is `log(k)` (the same subset, with `log` on each element), the problems are pretty much identical.

However, the DP solution generally used is very efficient for sums, since sum of elements don't tend to end up huge, while multiplying does. You also cannot take `log` on all elements and "work with it", because the numbers will not be integers - and the DP solution to subset sum requires integers to work on.

However, you can partially solve this issue by using [**Top-Down DP (memoization)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). This is fairly simple and is done as follows:

```
existenceOfSubset(set, product, map):
    if (product== 1):
           return true
    if (set.isEmpty()):
           return false
    if (map.containsKey(product)):
           return map.get(product)
    first = set.getFirst()
    set = set.removeFirst()
    solution = existenceOfSubset(set,product,map) OR (product%first == 0?existenceOfSubset(set,product/first,map):false) //recursive step for two possibilities
    map.put(product,solution  //memoize
    set.addFirst(first) //clean up
    return solution
```

invoke with `existenceOfSubset(set,product,new HashMap())`

Comment: It's **memoization**, without the r.

Comment: With top-down DP, do we really need logs? Can't our recursive step be without dividing by that element and with dividing if possible? (you still have a division in your code, I don't really get that).

Comment: @IVlad It's pretty much straight forward, like top-down of subset sum, but using the divide instead of substraction. There are no logs involved in this solution. The `log` was just explaining why it is a variant of subset sum, but is nowhere to be found in the algorithm itself.

Comment: Oh, I thought your code assumed you were working with the logs of the elements. In that case, shouldn't you call the function with `sum / first` only if `sum % first == 0`? `3 / 2 = 1`, but that shouldn't return true.

Comment: @IVlad It is covered in the first failing stop clause, it can be moved to there - it doesn't really matter (2nd thought it might matter to not allow floating points at all, even if they are only representing integers because of screwing up the hash functions).

Comment: Yes, +1, I think it's cleaner without floating points. One final nitpick: I  think the first two conditions should be swapped: if the sum is 1, you should return true regardless of whether or not the set is empty.

Comment: Since the log(k) is not an integer, how could DP work? You can't query and match the exact weight since when k become very large, log(k) ~= log(k-1) and there is no way to differentiate between the logarithmic values.

Comment: @zsong Exactly that is why we are not using log and using top-down DP instead

Comment: @amit Sorry, I meant to post the comment on the other answer. You can ignore it.

Comment: @amit the `//memorize` comment should be rewritten as `//memoize` as @IVlad said. Also some of the variable names are confusing, for example `sum` should be `product` and `sol` could be `solution`.

Comment: @LironYahdav Thanks for the feedback, updated with your input.